# PropertyChangedEventHandler causes memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, xamarin, eventhandler

I create Android app in xamarin.forms but problem is PropertyChangedEventHandler causes memory leak.

My code:

```
 protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

          if (handler != null)
    try {
         handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        } catch (Exception ex) 
        {

        }

    }
```

I test memory app in xamarin.profiler and result is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your implementation is solid.  Another thread-safe way to invoke the event in C# 6 is:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged( string propertyName )
    {
        PropertyChangedEventArgs e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName );
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke( this, e );
    }
```

I'm guessing the event subscription logic may be to blame.  Remember that event publishers keep their subscribers alive.  Here is a good article on event subscription and potential memory leaks. [Understanding and Avoiding Memory-Leaks](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2012/10/understanding-and-avoiding-memory-leaks.html)